# How to make selenium keep reloading page till find the right class_name?

Tags: python, selenium

How to make selenium keep reloading page (loop) till find the right `class_name`?

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('login').click();
```

I'm using js to reload:

```
driver.execute_script("location.reload()")
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by that? i doubt that the html of a website changes with reloading, can you somehow be more specific or add the url/html code?

Comment: I mean the button are locked, and will be unlock at certain times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an explicit_wait looking like this:

```
try:
element = driver.execute_script("location.reload()").until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "some id"))
)
```

finally:
element.click()
not exactly sure if everything is right with syntax, but i assume you get what i mean, you do it until the element is clickable. You need to import the following tho:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

i hope this works, please let me know if it does